# React not importing component properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this simple React code but is not importing properly, I don't know why.

```
import teste from './components/teste';
import './App.css';


function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
        <teste/>
    </Container>
  );
}

const Container = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
`

export default App;
```

also have the teste component

```
import React from 'react'

export default function teste() {
  return (
    <div>teste</div>
  )
}
```

This is the folder structure
[image]
could someone help me?

Comment: What happens? What is the error? That looks like vscode folder structure. What does vscode say about it?

Comment: `const Container = styled.div\`` looks like an error.

Answer (score 0):

In React, components are typically defined using capitalized names. When a component is defined with a name that starts with a lowercase letter, React may not recognize it as a component, leading to issues such as improper rendering of components or React not considering them valid.

To solve this, the component should be renamed to start with a capital letter, like 'Test', adhering to the convention for naming React components. By doing this, React will correctly recognize it as a component, thus eliminating issues related to component recognition.

Answer (score 0):

React treats components with lowercase names as DOM tags.

```
import React from 'react';
import Teste from './components/teste';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Teste />
    </Container>
  );
}

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
`;

export default App;


import React from 'react';

export default function Teste() {
  return (
    <div>teste</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @None it is in fact required. Otherwise you get an error and the component does not display... _"Warning: The tag <teste> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter."_